# Flowtype Polymorphism not working

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am trying to use Polymorphism for React components w/ inheritance, but I am seeing "This type is incompatible with some incompatible instantiation of V" error.

Here is the code:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react'

type BaseProps = {
    name: string
}

type BaseState<T> = {
    error: string,
    value: ?T,
}

class Base<Props, V> extends Component<any, BaseProps & Props, BaseState<V>> {
    state = {
        error: '',
        value: null,
    }
    render() {
        return <div>this.props.name</div>
    }
}


type ExtendedProps = {
    foo: string,
}

class ExtendedBase extends Base<ExtendedProps, string> {
    render () {
        return <div>this.props.name</div>
    }
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjQgGjAG8wBhOXOAOzI+IF8wo+NmADk+SjRHpCATxxkwAIQoBnMgAUhOFWAC8jVGCNgOFLGQBcYFYXwYOAc1S9pchcrUBlQhUJkAPAAqAHx6BsZgZPhC+FY2do60hsYAbhQwAK6WYAD8gUkuqFQwqjoeAZpw2vQAaqFkAB5+HAAmOqzsXDz+FBwy9OWV2mAAZGBDKgOqZN6+AXWhDMlGNnNhSxERUTFWIiJJm6npWVYcGTAwB8YuEeKtUQAUAJThh2DihBn4HGD+LRgpYKEAAWGBUADocFoIaZzP5gP9AcswC5CqhZPIwABRJrcFpkFoTdbIqBwOBxWz2BwFdDFUrY3H3FrlSKMtpKab+HHNfGE6H0eJUxbIu74-BgZ6vQ4fL4-P4AoGgiFQqowswBBEK5GooA).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Answered on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3091#issuecomment-269542870)

Had to defined types for state on Class.